# CKEditor insertHTML() in Inline mode

Tags: ckeditor, contenteditable

any way to use che InsertHTML CKeditor API to add HTML elements to a div using the inline mode?

I'm trying to solve e huge problem: I want to use the editor to design a page with some templates. If I use the standard CKEditor templates and I create a two column layout with nested div when i delete the placeholder text in one div the editor destroy the div and my layout is totally broken.

So I need to create a layout system where the structure is not editable and the nested div and paragraph are editable.

If I create something like this

```
<div contenteditable="false" class="grid_12">
<p contenteditable="true">blablabla</p>
</div>
```

insertHTML is not working, maybe ckeditor cannot recognize the nested contenteditable.

So I think that I can use the Inline Editing mode to edit my template mantaining the structure, but I don't know if in Inline Editing Mode I can add some external HTML snippets with InsertHTML Api.

I need this function because I insert every media object with this function!

Can anyone help me?

Comment: did you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably waiting for [widgets feature](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9764) that will be in CKEditor 4.2. At the moment what you want to do isn't supported by CKEditor.